# Use file creation date as archive name in batch archiving (7zip)

Tags: backup, bash, shell-scripting, archive

So what I basically want to achieve is to make archive of each file in a specified directory and so the name of resulted archive consisted of compressed file creation date.

Say we have some directory in which file A is located. The creation date of the A file is 2008-18-10-20:12:54 (we can ask `ls` to show us exactly that). So the resulted archive should be named *2008-18-10-20:12:54.7z* and be located in another directory.

The best I came with is the following:

```
for file in $HOME/tmp; do 
    7z a -mhe=on -mx=0 -p123456 $HOME/tmp-done/`ls -l "$HOME"/tmp/ --time-style=+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S "$file" | awk '{ print $6 }'`.7z $file;
done
```

As I understand it, the command above should instruct bash to read all files in a `~/tmp/` directory and then for each file execute 7z with arguments. One of the argument should be archive name computed form the creation date of archived file. And the archive file should be created in `~/tmp-done` directory.

It suppose to produce a batch of 7z files in `~/tmp-done/` directory, but instead it completely ignores `ls` part and creates a `~/home/done/.7z` file with all files compressed inside it.

I do think I am missing the way to deal with this sub command in argument part of 7z, but can't figure it out.

Any guide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try below bash script

```
set -ex

DIR_WITH_FILES="/tmp/myfiles"

DIR_WITH_ARCHIVES="/tmp/myarchives"

for file in $(ls -1 "${DIR_WITH_FILES}"); do 
    filename=$(ls -l --time-style=+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S "${DIR_WITH_FILES}/${file}" | awk '{ print $6 }')
    7z a -mhe=on -mx=0 -p123456 -- "${DIR_WITH_ARCHIVES}/${filename}.7z"  "${DIR_WITH_FILES}/${file}"
done
```